# Binary Search Tree Induction

Tags: induction, logarithms, trees

[image: problem]

So I know that it is true for $n = 1$ because $h \ge \log(1)\implies h \ge 0$. I also assume that $n=k$ is true. But how would I prove $h \ge \log_2{k+1}$. I tried to through log laws, but I'm quite stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that a Binary Tree of $n$ nodes has a height of at least $\log(n)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355163/proving-that-a-binary-tree-of-n-nodes-has-a-height-of-at-least-logn)